# Decomposition into irreducible representations

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I have some troubles when I try to decompose representations of $\mathfrak{gl}_n$ (for small $n$, of course) into irreducible ones. For example, how can I decompose $S^3(\mathbb{C}^3 \oplus (\mathbb{C}^3)^*)$ considered as a representation of $\mathfrak{gl}_3(\mathbb{C})$? Characters seem like a universal method, but it leads to gigantic crocodiles of rational functions. The same problem occurs in many other examples ($S^2 V_\lambda$, $S^3 V_\lambda$, small exterior powers etc).

Any tricks and useful experience are appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I certainly agree that we should avoid gigantic crocodiles. Do you have access to the book by Fulton and Harris on "Representation Theory, A First Course"?

Comment: @DietrichBurde Yes, I have, but don't have enough time to thoroughly read it :) at least now

Comment: You can use the identity $S^3(A \oplus B) = S^3(A) \oplus (S^2(A) \otimes B) \oplus (A \otimes S^2(B)) \oplus S^3(B)$, along with the fact that $S^k(\mathbb{C}^n)$ is the irreducible representation with highest weight $k \varpi_1$ for $\mathfrak{gl}_n$. Applying $S^k$ to an arbitrary represention is quite difficult I believe: the notion of _plethysm_ is a generalisation.